# Why is bootstrap button so wide?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got a jumbotron class which has to contain a button, but it's strangely extended and that button looks ugly. Why is that so?

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="row">    
      <div class="col-md-8">

        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">

          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">
            Why is this button so wide?
          </span>

        </button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.jumbotron {
    margin: 10px;
}

.row {
    margin: 8px 0;
}
```

If I try to reduce the size of the column, for example, **col-md-4**, nothing changes.

Comment: isnt it just as large as the text that you put into it? http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/356/

Comment: @indubitablee But it has too long indents between the words.

Comment: @indubitablee try to write at least three words.

Comment: Text belongs before or after your SPAN tag, not in it.

Comment: @vanburenx yep, it did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome and glad I could help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is you wrote the text inside icon `span`. Here is the fixed code

```css
.jumbotron {
    margin: 10px;
}

.row {
    margin: 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="row">    
      <div class="col-md-8">

        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
          Why is this button so wide?
        </button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

in main page use this...

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="intro-text">
            <div class="intro-lead-in">Welcome!!!</div>
            <div class="intro-heading">Let's Get Started</div>
            <a href="#" class="page-scroll btn btn-xl">Tell Me More</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

in css
use this

```
.btn-xl {
padding: 20px 40px;
border-color: #fed136;
border-radius: 3px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 700;
color: #fff;
background-color: #fed136;
```

}

this will solve your problem